# Kubernetes Network Policy Egress to pod via service

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, calico

I have some pods running that are talking to each other via Kubernetes services and not via the pod IP's and now I want to lock things down using Network Policies but I can't seem to get the egress right.

In this scenario I have two pods:

- `sleeper`, the client
- `frontend`, the server behind a Service called `frontend-svc` which forwards port 8080 to the pods port 80

Both running in the same namespace: `ns`

In the `sleeper` pod I simply `wget` a ping endpoint in the `frontend` pod:

`wget -qO- http://frontend-svc.ns:8080/api/Ping`

Here's my egress policy:

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: allow-to-frontend-egress
  namespace: ns
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sleeper
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: frontend
```

As you can see, nothing special; no ports, no namespace selector, just a single label selector for each pod.

Unfortunately, this breaks my ping:
`wget: bad address 'frontend-svc.ns:8080'`

However if I retrieve the pod's ip (using `kubectl get po -o wide`) and talk to the frontend directly I do get a response:
`wget -qO- 10.x.x.x:80/api/Ping` (x obviously replaced with values)

My intuition was that it was related to the pod's egress to the Kube-dns being required so I added another egress policy:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-egress-kube-system
  namespace: ns
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  egress:
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          kubernetes.io/metadata.name: "kube-system"
      podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

For now I don't want to bother with the exact pod and port, so I allow all pods from the `ns` namespace to egress to `kube-system` pods.

However, this didn't help a bit. Even worse: This also breaks the communication by pod ip.

I'm running on Azure Kubernetes with Calico Network Policies.

Any clue what might be the issue, because I'm out of ideas.

---

After getting it up and running, here's a more locked-down version of the DNS egress policy:

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: allow-all-pods-dns-egress
  namespace: ns
spec:
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  podSelector: {} 
  egress:
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          # This label was introduced in version 1.19, if you are running a lower version, label the kube-dns pod manually.
          kubernetes.io/metadata.name: "kube-system"  
      podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          k8s-app: kube-dns
    ports:
    - port: 53
      protocol: UDP
    - port: 53
      protocol: TCP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your deployment and the final networkpolicy (egress to `kube-system` for DNS resolution) solves it for me. Make sure that after applying the last network policy, you're testing the connection to service's port (8080) which you changed in you're `wget` command when accessing the pod directly (80).

Since network policies are a drag to manage, My team and I wanted to automate their creation and open sourced a tool that you might be interested in: https://docs.otterize.com/quick-tutorials/k8s-network-policies.

It's a way to manage network policies where you declare your access requirements in a separate, human-readable resource and the labeling is done for you on-the-fly.

Comment: I'm still not exactly sure what the problem was, but I got it running. I'll update my post one last time including a bit more locked-down version of the DNS egress policy for future reference.